# При установке модуля через NPM ошибка

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

При **npm i supermoduleoleg**

```
npm ERR! code ENOSELF
npm ERR! Refusing to install package with name "super
moduleoleg" under a package
npm ERR! also called "supermoduleoleg". Did you name
your project the same
npm ERR! as the dependency you're installing?
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For more information, see:
npm ERR!     <https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install#limi
tations-of-npms-install-algorithm>
```

В чем дело то?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что у вас есть package.json, в котором указано название пакета как `supermoduleoleg` и вы устанавливаете модуль с таким же названием (использовать [переводчик](http://translate.google.ru) никто ещё не запрещал)

Скорее всего вы ошиблись директорией и вместо папки проекта устанавливаете модуль в папку с модулем. В случае если вам по какой-то причине нужно в папку с проектом-модулем подгрузить тот же самый модуль, но через npm, то просто переименуйте проект в `package.json`

Comment: С П А С И Б О !